# Access only direct children of items returned within an HTMLcollection

Tags: javascript, xml, htmlcollection

I wish to get the list of all Boxers which are direct children of Group.

The XML is supplied from an external source. I have no control over its contents or format.

The Boxer tag gets used as a direct child of Group, and also as a grandchild of Group, via the Match tag.

```
<Round PhaseID="2" ID="Round 1">
    <Boxer REF="2"/>
    <Boxer REF="3"/>
    <Boxer REF="4"/>
    <Boxer REF="1"/>

    <Group ID="1">
      <Boxer REF="1" NumInGroup="2" NumVictories="0" NumMatches="2" PtsFor="0" PtsAgainst="0" GroupId="1"/>
      <Boxer REF="4" NumInGroup="1" NumVictories="0" NumMatches="2" PtsFor="0" PtsAgainst="0" GroupId="1"/>
      <Match ID="1">
        <Boxer REF="1"/>
        <Boxer REF="4"/>
      </Match>
      <Match ID="2">
        <Boxer REF="4"/>
        <Boxer REF="1"/>
      </Match>
    </Group>
    ...
</Round>
```

When I use

```
var groups = competitionDoc.getElementsByTagName("Group");  
var boxers = groups[0].getElementsByTagName("Boxer");
```

I get the list of all 6 tags named "Boxer" which are the descendants of the Group tag.

How do I get only the two direct children of Group?

Comment: I can see that the .parentElement attribute contains the information.  Is there a way to prune the HTMLcollection based on parentElement?

Answer (score 0):

As I iterate through all the elements returned by group[g].getElementsByTagName("Boxer") I turn the parentElement information into a string, and then I can make the code conditional on the first substring.

To turn groupBoxers[gb].parentElement into a string:

```
groupBoxers[gb].parentElement.outerHTML
```

Which returns, e.g.

```
<Group ID="1">
  <Boxer REF="1" NumInGroup="2" NumVictories="0" NumMatches="2" PtsFor="0" PtsAgainst="0" GroupId="1"/>
  <Boxer REF="2" NumInGroup="1" NumVictories="0" NumMatches="2" PtsFor="0" PtsAgainst="0" GroupId="1"/>

  <Match ID="1">
    <Boxer REF="1"/>
    <Boxer REF="2"/>
  </Match>

</Group>
```

I then iterate through all the elements returned by group[g].getElementsByTagName("Boxer"), and I can

```
  if (groupBoxers[gb].parentElement.outerHTML.substring(1,6) == "Group") {
     // do something with this Boxer - it is a direct child of a Group
  }
```